# HTML Template for Outlook not working correctly

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a pretty specific requirement for an email template format. I have the following template which pulls properties from a helpdesk system. When users/analysts respond I need the formatting of the comments/descriptions to be preserved but at the same time if the text is too wide, for example an email link, to wrap it within a specific size. The template below works fine in IE however goes completely wrong within outlook. This is the body of the email as rendered by outlook.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p,
    td,
    tr,
    table {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      border-left: solid 0px border-right: solid 0px border-top: solid 0px border-bottom: solid 0px border: solid 0px
    }
    table,
    td,
    tr,
    th {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      color: #FFF;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .blacktextcentre {
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    .blacktextleft {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
    }
    .whitetextleft {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .whitetextcentre {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #A6A6A6;
    }
    .blacktextleftbold {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .blacktextrightbold {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    tr.border_bottom td {
      border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
    }
    .blacktextcentreheading {
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tableborder {
      background-color: #007864;
    }
    pre.text {
      white-space: pre-line;
      width: 400px;
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    img {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<table width="600" border="0" align="center">
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="120">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <img src="logo" hspace="10" vspace="10">
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Update</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">Dear Alex</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">The Service Desk have updated your request. Please find a summary below.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Summary</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">ID:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">IR1174</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Title:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">Printer - Not Working</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Time Added:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">31/05/2016 17:03:40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Comment:</td>
          <td><pre class="text">cxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
cxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv</pre>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Further Information</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">To update your ticket then please visit the <a HREF="server">portal</a> to provide an update or click on the link to <a HREF="mailto:address?subject=[IR1174]&body=">reply</a>.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Kind regards,</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Service Desk</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Any thoughts on how to preserve the formatting but keep within a specific width welcome

This is how outlook renders it
[image: Error]

This is how IE renders it and how it should look

[image]

This is the position of the pre.text class
[image]

I've put in the changes recommended below and this is what comes back:
[image]

And this is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p, td, tr, table {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 border-left: solid 0px
 border-right: solid 0px
 border-top: solid 0px
 border-bottom: solid 0px
 border: solid 0px
}
table, td, tr, th {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 14px;
 
}
.blacktextcentre {
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
}
.blacktextleft {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
}

.whitetextleft {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
}
.whitetextcentre {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 background-color:#A6A6A6;
}

.blacktextleftbold {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.blacktextrightbold {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
}
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
.blacktextcentreheading {
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.tableborder {
 background-color:#007864;
}
pre.text{
white-space: pre-line;
width: 400px;
font-family: "Arial";
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
img{
padding: 10px;
}
.master-table {
width:600px;
}
</style>
</head>

<table class="master-table">
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="120">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><img src="https://link/Content/images/maillogo.jpg" hspace="10" vspace="10"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Update</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">Dear Alex</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">The Service Desk have updated your request. Please find a summary below.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Summary</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10">
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">ID:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">IR1174</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Title:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">Printer - Not Working</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Time Added:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">01/06/2016 09:16:20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Comment:</td>
        <td><pre class="text">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</pre></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Further Information</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">To update your ticket then please visit the <a HREF="https://server">portal</a> to provide an update or click on the link to <a HREF="mailto:mail@mail.org?subject=[IR1174]&body=">reply</a>.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Kind regards,</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Service Desk</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add images to show what's right and what's wrong

Comment: Thanks, blind moment looking for the edit button

Comment: Outlook is known to have issues, i would say make sure that you have fixed widths on tables. also validate your html and css https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Somewhere deeply hidden in the MSDN ressources there is a list of supported HTML features in the according Outlook versions.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the width attribute to the td-cell containing the text

```
<td width="510"><pre class="text">blablabla</pre></td>
```

Comment: makes no difference, width still get's over-ridden somehow by the length of the text. The pre.text formats the width of the text correctly however it gets centred in the middle of the cell which is the width of the longest text string

Comment: its some years ago i had to work with that, but next try would be an extra <p style="word-wrap:break-word;"> for the text.

Comment: Using p instead of pre results in losing the existing formatting present in the original text property, i.e. line breaks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following
Your text needs line breaks, also as i mentioned validate your css validator.w3.org

```
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p,
    td,
    tr,
    table {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      border-left: solid 0px border-right: solid 0px border-top: solid 0px border-bottom: solid 0px border: solid 0px
    }
    table,
    td,
    tr,
    th {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      color: #FFF;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 14px;
    }

.master-table {
    width:600px;
}

    .blacktextcentre {
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    .blacktextleft {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
    }
    .whitetextleft {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .whitetextcentre {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #A6A6A6;
    }
    .blacktextleftbold {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .blacktextrightbold {
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    tr.border_bottom td {
      border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
    }
    .blacktextcentreheading {
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tableborder {
      background-color: #007864;
    }
    pre.text {
      white-space: pre-line;
      width: 400px;
      font-family: "Arial";
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    img {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<table class="master-table">
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="120">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <img src="logo" hspace="10" vspace="10">
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Update</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">Dear Alex</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">The Service Desk have updated your request. Please find a summary below.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Summary</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">ID:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">IR1174</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Title:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">Printer - Not Working</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="border_bottom">
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Time Added:</td>
          <td class="blacktextleft">31/05/2016 17:03:40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="90" class="blacktextrightbold">Comment:</td>
          <td><pre class="text">cxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvv
vvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcxvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv</pre>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Further Information</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">To update your ticket then please visit the <a HREF="server">portal</a> to provide an update or click on the link to <a HREF="mailto:address?subject=[IR1174]&body=">reply</a>.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Kind regards,</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Service Desk</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The original problem mentioned long lines with generated links that lead to the problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made any difference to it I'm afraid. It amazes me that one of the most widely used email client's can't handle simple html

Comment: This is due to EU legislative regulation... they ruled, that windows should be available without Internet Exploder, so MS decided to use the Word HTML-Renderer for Outlook 2003/2007. Believe me, this plagues IT people all over the planet since many years now. Check out fixoutlook.org for example. If my clients were resistant to my advice and said: "my webdev guy said you should just use style="bla:blabla;" i would just give them the MSDN-List of supported HTML-Features in Outlook 2003/2007. That always helped :)

Comment: ah i forgot to mention: Lotus Notes < 8 is even worse, because it converts to RTF before display :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I've cracked it. By fixing the width of the subtable containing the pre-section it's now behaving:

[image]

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p, td, tr, table {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 border-left: solid 0px
 border-right: solid 0px
 border-top: solid 0px
 border-bottom: solid 0px
 border: solid 0px
}
table, td, tr, th {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 14px;
 
}
.blacktextcentre {
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
}
.blacktextleft {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
 padding:5px;
}

.whitetextleft {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
}
.whitetextcentre {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 background-color:#A6A6A6;
}

.blacktextleftbold {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:5px;
}
.blacktextrightbold {
 font-family: "Arial";
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:5px;
 width:100px;
}
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
.blacktextcentreheading {
 font-family: "Arial";
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.tableborder {
 background-color:#007864;
}
pre.comment{
white-space: pre-line;
font-family: "Arial";
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000;
word-wrap: break-word;
width:440px;
}
img{
padding: 10px;
}
.master-table {
width:600px;
}
.subtable {
width:550px;
table-layout:fixed;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="master-table">
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="120">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><img src="https://web/maillogo.jpg" hspace="10" vspace="10"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Update</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">Dear Alex</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">The Service Desk have updated your request. Please find a summary below.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Ticket Summary</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table class="subtable">
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td class="blacktextrightbold">ID:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">IR1174</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td class="blacktextrightbold">Title:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">Printer - Not Working</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td class="blacktextrightbold">Time Added:</td>
        <td class="blacktextleft">01/06/2016 10:43:19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blacktextrightbold">Comment:</td>
        <td style="padding:5px; text-align:left;"><pre class="comment">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</pre></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="whitetextcentre">Further Information</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="35">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextleft">To update your ticket then please visit the <a HREF="https://link">portal</a> to provide an update or click on the link to <a HREF="mailto:mail@mail.org?subject=[IR1174]&body=">reply</a>.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Kind regards,</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="blacktextcentre">Service Desk</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tableborder">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableborder">
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```